# How Cassandra store data for materialized views

Tags: cassandra, datastax, bigdata, nosql

I am wondering what's the cost for the disk space for the materialized views?

If I have a base table with 10 fields, primary keys are f1, f2, f3. I create one  materialized view from it, which include all the 10 fields, primary keys are f4, f1, f2, f3.

How much disk space the materialized view takes?

Almost same disk as the base table?

Or the materialized view only uses disk for its primary keys f4, f1, f2, f3.

I kind of think it's the first case. - as materialized view is implemented as a normal Cassandra table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supposition is correct -- it will take about the same amount of disk space as the base table. The materialized view is implemented as a distinct table, and no data de-duplication is done.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking is present in detail in the below link ; -

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/materialized-view-performance-in-cassandra-3-x

Comment: This is a [link-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks, Piyush, I do read more than 10 links about materialized views including this one before ask question here. I din'd find articles that specify the cost of disk space for materialized views. Although I can do some educated guess, but it would be great if someone familiar with materialized views can tell us the exact answer. Thanks.